# Recursive regex pattern match in python

Tags: python, regex, recursion

I'm trying to match recursive pattern in python but i'm missing something and getting errors.

I want to achieve:

```
var = [a-z]+
digit = [0-9]+
op=+,-,*,/
E->var|digit|op E E
```

eg:

```
"+ x 1", 

"* x * y + x y"
```

This is my code:

```
import re
term="[a-z]+|[0-9]+"
op=[+-/*]
exp="("+term+"|("+op+" "+term+" "+term+")|(?R))
```

sow when I do `re.match(exp,"+ x 1")`, I'm getting :

> "sre_constants.error: unexpected end of pattern"

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: the `re` module doesn't have a recursion feature, if you need it, install and  use the `regex` module. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: I did the substitution and there is not really any regex problem. Not sure but should `+")|(?R))` be terminated with a double quote? As for the recursion, I don't see any nesting, are you just testing recursion for it's own sake?

Comment: hi sin, how can i do that with substitution. A simple example would help. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [`(?:[-+/*]*\s*(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)\s*|\s*(?:[-+/*]\s+(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)\s+(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+))+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/uV0wW5/1) will work for you without recursion?

Comment: but it also matches "+x x x 1" and "+ + x 1" which is not right pattern

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/7F8R3B/1, have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a non-recursive regex with built-in `re`:

```
^[+/*-] ?(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)(?: ?(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+))?(?: [+/*-] ?(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)(?: ?(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+))?)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GO4Ceo/1)

The pattern follows a specific scheme: `^block{{op} ?{term}(?: ?{term})?}(?: {block})*$`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[+/*-] ?(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)(?: ?(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+))?` - **block** part:

  - `[+/*-]` - *op*: `+`, `/`, `*` or `-`
  - `\?` - an optional space
  - `(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)` - **term** part: 1+ lowercase letters or 1+ digits
  - `(?: ?(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+))?` - an optional sequence of:
  - `\?` - an optional space
  - `(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)` - "term" pattern
- `(\?:`  - start of the non-capturing group and a space

  - `[+/*-] ?(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)(?: ?(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+))?` - the "block" pattern
- `)*` - end of the non-capturing group, repeat 0 or more times
- `$` - end of string.

In Python:

```
op = r'[+/*-]'
term = r'(?:[a-z]+|[0-9]+)'
block = rf'{op} ?{term}(?: ?{term})?'
pattern = rf'^{block}(?: {block})*$'
```

Use `re.match` or `re.search` with the pattern to validate.